# i have a matrix mtx file til sort out:

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, matrix

I have two types of codes:

this one, I can extract all characters from the mtx file, but when I run it, I can't get the last two words of the first line, I can't skip the lines with '%' characters and empty lines, and I can't separate the matrix dimensions and their values into their own set of array. Also, the first line with numbers are integers that count numbers of dimensions and entries, And I want to make a for loop that count the entrees and separates the values on its own array so I can calculate their frobinius_norm in scientific notation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void processLine(const string &line)
{
    string first, second, third;
    if ( line[0]&&line[1] == '%' )
    {
        //extract last 2 words
        cout <<line << endl;
    } else if (line[0]=='%')
    {
       //ignore the lines
        cout << line << endl;
    } else {
        /*seperate matrix dimensions and values,
        but the first one is x*y dimension and number of entries*/
        cout << line << endl;
}
}

void processFile(const char *filename)
{
    ifstream inf(filename);
    if ( inf.is_open() ) {
        string line,type;
        while ( getline(inf,line) ) {
       processLine(line);
    }
    } else {
        cout << "Sorry, but the file don't exist!\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc==2){
    cout <<"Filename: " << argv[1] << endl;
        processFile(argv[1]);
} else {
    cout << "give a filename\n";
}
}
```

and this one, i can successfully extract all information on the first matrix file: **sparse01.mtx**:

%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate pattern general
9 9 50
1 1
2 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 1
8 1
9 1
2 2
3 2
...
9 9

but the sparse02.mtx and sparse03.mtx matrix I can't modify the code to give me correct result, because I can't ignore the lines with a beginning character '%' and empty lines. I can't really count the entrees and seperates dimensions and values, and because of that I cant calculate frobinius norm...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string filename, line, type1, type2, header;
    int x, y, entry, count=0;
    double element;
    char norm;
    float frobenius_norm;
    ifstream openfile;

    filename = argv[1];
    openfile.open(argv[1]);

    if(!openfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Sorry, but the file don't exist!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i =0;i<2;i++)
    {
        getline(openfile,line,' ');
    }

    getline(openfile,header,' ');
    getline(openfile,type1,' ');
    getline(openfile,type2);
    if(getline(openfile,line).peek()=='%'){
        cout << "lol"<<endl;
    }
    openfile >> x >> y >> entry;



    cout <<"Filename: " << filename << endl;
    cout <<"Dimensions: " << x << " x " << y << endl;
    cout <<"Entries: " << entry <<endl;

    if(header == "coordinate")
    {
        cout <<"Sparse: "<< "true" <<endl;
    }
    else if ((x*y/2)<entry||header == "array")
    {
     cout <<"Sparse: "<< "false" <<endl;
    }

    cout <<"Type: "<< type1 << ' ' << type2 <<endl;

    if(type1 == "pattern"){
        norm = '-';
        cout <<"Frobenius norm: "<< norm <<endl;
    } else {
        frobenius_norm = 100;
        cout <<"Frobenius norm: "<< frobenius_norm <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output should be like this

Filename: sparse01.mtx
Dimensions: 9 x 9
Entries: 50
Sparse: true
Type: pattern general
Frobenius norm: -

%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate pattern general
9 9 50
1 1
2 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 1
... (truncated)
9 9

the output for sparse03 matrix is this:
Filename: sparse03.mtx
Dimensions: 5 x 5
Entries: 10
Sparse: true
Type: real general
Frobenius norm: 1.2e+02

this is sparse03.mtx file (this is not a code but an input file):

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
%
% Hello
% How
% Are
% you
% doing
%

5  5  10
1  1  11.0
1  5  15.0  
2  3  23.0  
2  4  24.0  
3  2  32.0    
3  5  35.0   
4  1  41.0  
5  2  52.0
5  4  54.0
5  5  55.0
```

I also want my code to calculate the dense and special matrix:

keep in mind that i used argv[1] as input reference

Comment: Well `if ( line[0]&&line[1] == '%' )` should be `if (line[0] == '%' && line[1] == '%' )` C++ doesn't parse the same way as English.

Comment: ok thanks, now the next step...